# Нужна помощь. Не Работает поиск по базе данных в php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Форма:

```
<form action="search_db.php" method="post">
    Ищем по:
    <select name="searchtype">
        <option value="gamintojas" selected>Производитель
        <option value="usakymodata">Дата заказа
        <option value="aprasas">Описание товара
        <option value="kiekis">Количество
        <option value="kaina">цена
    </select>
    Что ищем: <input name="searchterm">
    <input type=submit value="Поиск">
</form>
```

Код:

```
    $searchterm = trim ( $_POST['searchterm'] );
    if (!$searchterm)
    die ("Не все данные введены.<br>
    Пожалуйста, вернитесь назад и закончите ввод");
    $searchterm = addslashes ($searchterm);
    $link = new mysqli("localhost", "nerka","ooz7Geer", "nerka");
    if (!$link)
    {
    echo "Prisijungimas nepavyko <br>";
    }
    else {
    echo "Prisijungimas sekmingas <br>";
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sandelis WHERE " .$_POST['searchtype']." like 
   '%".$searchterm."%'";
    $result = mysql_query ( $query );
    $n = mysql_num_rows ( $result );
    for ( $i=0; $i<$n; $i++ )
    {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<p><b>".($i+1). $row['gamintojas']. "</b><br>";
    echo "Автор: ".$row['usakymodata']."<br>";
    echo "ISBN: ".$row['aprasas']."<br>";
    echo "Количество: ".$row['kiekis']."<br>";
    echo "цена: ".$row['kaina']."</p>";
    }
    if ( $n == 0 ) echo "Ничего не можем предложить. Извините";
    mysql_close ( $link );
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы подключаете драйвер **mysqli**, но далее по коду вызываете методы драйвера **mysql**. Это так не работает.